# pass data from angularjs controller to C# MVC CTRL

Tags: c#, angularjs, http, model-view-controller

this is simple but it dosent work

in angularJS part i have this code :

```
   var data={"ID":1,"Key":"********"}
            $http.post("/Home/DeleteListItem", data)
                .success(function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.parse(data));
                }).error(function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                });
```

and C# Part is like this

```
 [HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteListItem(Entity entity)

{

kishAppEntities db = new kishAppEntities();
Stream req = Request.InputStream;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var data = //some delete query

return new JsonResult()
{
    Data = data,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

};

}


public  class Entity
{
    int ID { set; get; }
    string Key { set; get; }

}
```

there is no data in entity i dont have clue aboute it????
[image]

i use this post method as second approach but still dosent work

```
     var entity = { "ID": 1, "Key": "********" }
        $http({
            url: "./general/DeleteListItem",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                entity: entity
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {           
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Based upon the provided code, I can say that angular promise usage is wrong. use $http.post("/Home/DeleteListItem", data).then(function(successResponse){}, function(errorResponse) {});

Comment: i dont have a error. problem is i dont get my post data from client

Comment: please see update

Comment: Please check my answer below. using .success is not a right way in asynchronous call. refer: http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID and Key properties are not accessible. Put before your properties ***public*** access modifier like this:

```
public  class Entity
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Key { set; get; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery $.param(data).
You can also try angular $httpParamSerializer https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$http.post("/Home/DeleteListItem", data)
.then(function(successResponse){
//Your code to handle response

}, 
function(errorResponse) {
//your code to handle error
});
```

Comment: Is that returns any error? Also, check if the call hitting your MVC controller method. Note you won't get the result immediately.

Comment: it call mvc contoller and return whit no errore if you see the photo i debug my controller so it call the method it just not have my payload data

Comment: sorry.. my network blocks image loading. Please use the [FromBody] attribute on your controller parameter : public JsonResult DeleteListItem([Frombody] Entity entity)
{

Comment: vs ide dos note recognized [Frombody]

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. it should be [FromBody]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130746/discussion-between-kalyana-sundaram-and-pooria-shariatzadeh).